# Making sure my RandomForestRegressor actually makes sense of data and doesn't just interpret random noise?

Tags: validation, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, random-forest

I have a small and a heterogenous dataset of 260 datapoints. There are 9 mixed features (4 categorical, 5 continuous) and I'm trying to predict a continuous value of material in tonnes which is my only label.

I'm using RandomForestregressor in scikit-learn and a tuned model renders a non-impressive, but fairly consistent results of R2 = 0.4 and MAE of 8.4 (std of the label is 19.2) with 10 folds CV.

A whole task serves me as a proof of concept for a master thesis, I collected and cleaned the dataset myself, it's a real-world data and I know that it might have many errors (but well, it's the best we've got and I don't have a way to measure HOW unreliable/reliable it is). So I wanted to check if I can even trust these results or maybe the model just finds some patterns in a complete noise and a whole dataset is complete garbage.

So what I did was creating a new dataset of the same shape, but with values shuffled per feature (calling a random number within an expected range per feature). Then when I ran my model on this new 'garbage' dataset, the results were R2 = -0.2 and MAE = 20.6. Which I guess is GOOD, since it'd mean there is some correlation picked up in my original model and it is actually valid.

Is what I've done a legit experiment to validate that the model is useful? Does an approach like this have a name or are there problems with it? If so, can I do something different to validate the model?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is similar to permutation-based feature importance calculation (i.e. `sklearn.inspection.permutation_importance`), where you shuffle every feature separately and measure the model metrics decrease (except you actually actually shuffle the order rather than generating new values). As you see, at least some of your model features seem to be helpful. Dropping useless or redundant features (using mutual information, VIF etc) might improve your model further unless you've already done so.

sklearn also provides dummy models with different strategies (see `sklearn.dummy.DummyRegressor`), which you can check your model against. You're checking different metrics, which is important as well: I've seen models losing to the constant mean value predictor despite the obvious R2 difference.

R2 score of 0.4 means your models explains 40% of the target variance, and your absolute error is much better than your dummy model one. This is averaged between 10 cross-validation folds so it seems pretty solid. For extremely small datasets, you may go up to Leave-One-Out cross-validation, but it looks like a bit of an overkill in your case.